# Docker container fails with file not found

Tags: docker, tomcat, dockerfile

I am trying to create a docker container as follows with JMX set

```
FROM tomcat:7-jre8-alpine

RUN apk --update add fontconfig ttf-dejavu

ADD setenv.sh bin

WORKDIR /usr/local/tomcat
ADD management.properties .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "catalina.sh", "run" ]
```

My management properties file is referenced in my setenv.sh file. This file is in the root folder

```
echo "SETENV RUNNING"
JMX_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote - Dcom.sun.management.config.file=$CATALINA_BASE/management.properties"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS $JMX_OPTS"
```

when I try to start my container I see a failure.

```
SETENV RUNNING
Error: Config file not found: /usr/local/tomcat/management.properties
```

I checked the user permissions and doesn't seem to be an issue. Any direction is much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Add `management.properties` to the correct folder:

```
...
WORKDIR /usr/local/tomcat
ADD management.properties
...
```

Comment: My mistake.. I had older error listed. See correct error in the question now.

Comment: use `WORKDIR /usr/local/tomcat` and then add the file?

Comment: no change. I updated the question with complete files